# Can neutrino oscillates into antineutrino?

Tags: antimatter, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

Unlike antineutron, an antineutrino aren't made up of antiquarks so how do we tell an antineutrino from ordinary neutrino? Can majorana particle oscillates between matter particle and antiparticle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neutrinos might be their own antiparticles. (If we ever observe neutrinoless double beta decay, we'll know this is true.) Currently it is believed they probably aren't, in which case the oscillation you describe would be expected to be impossible as it would violate lepton number conservation.

Comment: Even with Majorana neutrinos an observation of switching from one chiral state to another (in effect changing from normal to anti or vice versa) is constrained by the intense Lorentz focusing of the direction of angular momentum. It's not exactly impossible, but for neutrinos of the currently observable energies it is 'impossibly unlikely'. Of course available neutrino sources are very intense, so it ought to be observable if you could get nearly perfect background rejection, but that is a bit beyond the state of the art. This is basically the reason neutrinoless double beta decay is rare.